# What are the differences between a laundry / sink tap breecher and a shower breecher?

Tags: shower, renovation, laundry

I am in the process of renovating my laundry, and I want to install a new shower where the old trough was. My idea was to just attach a shower rose to the existing tap outlet. I had a plumber look at it an he said that he couldn't install a shower on a laundry breecher.
I had a look at both in the shop an couldn't see any meaningful differences that would prevent a shower head being attached to the laundry trough breecher.
Did I miss something, or was the plumber being pedantic?

Edit: location is Australia

Comment: Where in the world? (Not your address, but what plumbing code applies varies by country, and sometimes smaller divisions.) Please [edit] to add that information - Thanks! Under my applicable code that's probably not yours ("Breecher" not being a familiar word is a clue) the laundry sink would probably have a drain too small for the minimum required for a shower drain.

Comment: I think a breecher is a handle configuration where two separate taps (hot and cold) feed a T, which continues on to the shower head or faucet. This guy is probably in Australia.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. In which case it might be a lack of the (pretty much globally) required anti-scald for showers... But I would think that could be installed as an in-line tempering valve - but code might not accept it?

Comment: yeah, Longneck is correct. eg: https://www.reece.com.au/search/pipe-fittings-c513/copper-pipe-fittings-c525/breeches-c950.  an in-line tempering valve would need a separate cold connection

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. I'm in Australia as guessed, have edited the post to show that.

Comment: If I'm using a rail and flexi-hose shower head like this one https://tradelink.com.au/tasman-ii-rail-shower-123941/ does the long neck serve any purpose?